# Tailwindcss with flexbox do not grow with horizontal description

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwindcss. How can I make sure the label is not growing with the description?

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex items-center">
    <div>block</div>

    <div class="ml-6">
        <p>
            Title
        </p>
        
        <p class="bg-blue-500">
            Description long long long long long long long long long long long long long 
        </p> 

        <div class="px-2 py-1 bg-red-500 rounded-xl text-xs text-gray-700">
            Label...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add class `w-fit` to the label div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `w-fit` or inline display styles to `<div ...> Label...` like `inline` or `inline-block`

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex items-center">
    <div>block</div>

    <div class="ml-6">
        <p>
            Title
        </p>
        
        <p class="bg-blue-500">
            Description long long long long long long long long long long long long long 
        </p> 

        <div class="px-2 py-1 bg-red-500 rounded-xl text-xs text-gray-700 w-fit">
            Label...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```